# Noob Alert! Particle system Orientation

Tags: particles

I'm very new to Blender and couldn't figure this one out for the life of me!

I can't get the seed to follow the shape of the bun... I tried all possible rotations and found nothing online about it. It's probably something simple, but couldn't figure it out! Hope I'm in the right place though!

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the object you used as the "main" particle (the big one above), enter edit mode, select the whole thing and rotate it 90 degrees on the X-axis.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, I remember trying it and not working. But this one works! :) Thanks a million Chris!